# Is it normal for gcov to peg the CPU at 100%

Tags: performance, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I'm running gcov (through lcov) over a medium-sized project. It's had the CPU at close to 100% for quite a while (not sure exactly how long, but over 30 minutes). The memory isn't ballooning. It seems to be stuck on one task.

Is it normal for gcov to do this kind of thing?

**Edit**

No luck. Just had to exclude the piece of code that correlated to the hang.

Comment: Is it gcov itself that is stuck?  Or your application after applying gcov?

Comment: It's running gcov to get the analysis that's the problem. The gcov process is the one that's hanging.